# google colab-Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... error ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am in windows OS. I am using  google colab ,I get these error ,when I run the code .I find this link [https://lxml.de/installation.html]. I dont familiar with Linux，so how to resolve it just in google colab. Any hint would be appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaAem.png)

`!pip install -q kaggle`

`!pip install -q kaggle-cli`

Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... error

ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml

```
Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-g0j7kmu8/lxml_93339675a71644a6aa1498a90b070e38/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-g0j7kmu8/lxml_93339675a71644a6aa1498a90b070e38/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-u1erza7w/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.7/lxml Check the logs for full command output.